# My appium is founded the element but Cannot click element. it's say "Cannot click. The element is found but not visible on Screen"

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

i have following this code

```
            try{Thread.sleep(2000);} catch(Exception ignore){}
            w8_Dirty.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='Reject Inspect']")));
            Dirty.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnRejectDirty']")).click();
```

so i try to wait until element is enable but it won't work. it said

> unknown error (An unknown server-side error occurred. status='false'. Failed to complete internal method: 'click args: [NATIVE, xpath=(//*[@id='btnRejectDirty'])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR5J6.jpg), 0, 1]', details: Failed to click 'xpath=(//*[@id='btnRejectDirty'])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR5J6.jpg)'. Cannot click. The element is found but not visible on Screen)  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

what should i do?.
PS.I use java.

[image: This is the element that i want to click it's show on the screen but my appium can't click]

[image: this image show that element can clickable]

Comment: Consider scrolling to view in question, to make it fully visible on screen before action.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is actually happening on the screen and what **element is enabled** means, but here are my suggestions.
Obviously, driver can not click on the element if it is not visible (you can see such reason in the log). You can scroll to it and then click on it with the following method:

```
public void scrollToElementByText(String text) {
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\").instance(0))");
}
```

You can scroll to element by `text` or `description` for example.
Other suggestion is that the elemnt is not `clickable` so you can not perform `click()` on it. To clarify that situation paste here some screenshot with DOM tree of this particular element in it.

Comment: thx guy but my element is already show up in the screen (u can see my picture. sry for forget to add picture before.)

Comment: show me attributes of this element i bet it is not clickable

Answer (score 1):

TouchAction touchActions = new TouchAction(driver);

```
    touchActions.press(PointOption.point(100,1000))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(100, 50)).release().perform();
```

Scroll using this code